# React Native compare value between items in flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I'm new in React Native. I would like to ask if it is possible to compare the value of previous item in the flatlist after a new item is added.

For example, I added one item with value of 10. Then I add another item in the flatlist with value of 30. After I press the 'Add' Button, it will automatically alert saying that the difference between the previous and new item is 20.

Also, it should not be a problem I create the id of the item using Math.random() right? Thank you for your suggestion and support in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try inside the method where you render items populate the array with the values and use indexes to calculate the differences. For example, now you have two items in the array. Once button is pressed do

```
 array[array.length - 2] - array[array.length - 1].
```

If you are familiar with OOP you can define constructor and create array there as this.array = [];

Comment: Okay Danny. I will try to implement that and see how it goes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. I've prepared a snack here:

https://snack.expo.dev/@moistbobo/so-69228068

Here, I use the `useState` hook to keep track of the array of values.

Then, in the `onAdd` handler, I check if the length of the `values` array is greater than 1 and if it is, I show an alert with the difference. This is to prevent an error if the array is empty. I do the difference calculation before adding it to the state so that `values.length - 1` will always refer to the last element in the `values` array.

> Also, it should not be a problem I create the id of the item using Math.random() right?

The id of the items won't affect the logic above. You would just have to keep track of an array of objects instead of an array of numbers like in my example, as well as change the logic on line 17 to use the object's value for the subtraction.

Although its out of the scope of this question, it's generally not a good idea to use `Math.random()` to generate id's, as there is a high chance for 2 items to have the same id. A good alternative for id generation is [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid).

Comment: Okay Moistbobo. i really appreciate the snack you prepared and the explanation is very helpful and understandable and also thank you for the suggestion about the alternative for id generation.

Comment: BTW, since I am using android studio emulator for my project. how can I replace " import Constants from 'expo-constants' " ?

Comment: If you're not using expo (i.e if you created the project using the cli) you don't need to import expo-constants

Comment: oh okay. thank you again Moistbobo. I really appreciate it :D